# Problems Flash(Flex) in .NET WebBrowser component

Tags: .net, webbrowser-control

We have a problem with Flash in the .NET WebBrowser component. At a customer of ours, on half of the computers (150) the candidates can click on a Flex ComboBox but they cannot select anything in the ComboBox. If they click on an item in the ComboBox, the ComboBox closes itself but the item is not selected.

A possible idea we have is that somehow flash loses focus when a candidate clicks on a ComboBox. When the candidate clicks on an item, Flash first regains focus by the click, the ComboBox is automatically closed and no item is selected. So when the candidate clicks on the item, it really just clicks on the swf to get focus... Could this be the problem and how would we solve it? + Why is it, that on half of the computers, it does work?

I have also seen that there's also a Microsoft Web Browser Com Control available. I'll see if it works with that Control.

Comment: The Windows Forms WebBrowser control class is based on the ActiveX shipped with IE, so there would be no difference in terms of ActiveX support.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

We have noticed this problem as well but only when a non-service packed version of .NET 2.0 is installed.  If .NET 2.0 SP1 is installed the issue resolved itself for us.

I have also found [this post](http://www.vbdotnetforums.com/vb-net-general-discussion/18563-webbrowser-control-2-0-framework-flash-fix.html) which would imply that it is a bug in the framework that you could theoretically work around if installing the service pack on the end users machine is not an option.

Comment: Good to know. Will check this.

Comment: @Joe: Do you mean on the pc of the developer or pc of the person using the application?

Comment: The user running the application

Comment: Worked like a charm. thx! http://blog.johlero.eu/2010/05/04/webbrowser-control-flash-dropdown-fix-framework-2-0/